# redirecting with primary key from views.py

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view

```
 (user_list.html) 
 {% extends "base.html" %}
 {% load static %}




 {% block content %}
   <div class="list_main">
     <div class="container">
     {% for user in user_list %}

     <ul>
       <li><a href="{% url 'myapp:detail' pk=user.pk %}">
        <div class="jumbotron">
         <h4 class="list_content">{{user.name}}</h4>
        </div>
       </a></li>
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}

  <div class="bttn">
  <p><a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'myapp:user' %}">Add</a></p>
 </div>

 </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here with the help of

```
 <p><a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'myapp:user' %}">Add</a></p>
```

I am calling  (views.py --> UserView)

```
 def UserView(request):

      response = requests.get('https://randomuser.me/api')
      data = response.json()

      title = data['results'][0]['name']['title']
      first = data['results'][0]['name']['first']
      last = data['results'][0]['name']['last']


      final_name = " ".join([first,last])

      #############################################
      final_name = ". ".join([title, final_name])          #Final name of the user


      #############################################
      agee = data['results'][0]['dob']['age']               # age of the user


      user = UserData.objects.create( name = final_name, age= agee, gender = gender)
      user.save()


      return redirect('detail', pk=user.pk) #This is not working
```

what I want to do is whenever the button from template (user_list.html) is clicked.
 I want to enter this function in my views.py file perform the operations and redirect to

```
 (path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),)
```

My views.UserDetailView

```
 class UserDetailView(DetailView):
 model = UserData
 context_object_name = 'user_detail'
 template_name = 'user_detail.html'
```

As shown in the code in( UserView(request) ), I have tried "return redirect('detail', pk=user.pk) "
this does not work.

Also please tell me if there is more neat and efficient way available to perform operations present in 
 ( UserView(request) ) when button is clicked in ( user_list.html ) and then redirect from "UserView" to ((path('detail//', views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed app name `myapp` when using redirect:

```
return redirect('myapp:detail', pk=user.pk)
```